# Trim a Clipping Mask in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, crop

Is it possible to trim a `clipping mask` in **Illustrator**? I have an image that I created a mask for, but the entire image is so much larger than the space I need, I would like to crop the rest of the image to the mask.

Basically, I need the same result as in Photoshop when you **Right-click > Apply Mask**.

[image: This is what I'm after]

Comment: I know this is an old post. But many people is directed here with the same question: Here's the best solution I found: (6 easy steps, about 10sec...) http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-how-to-crop-raster-image-in-adobe-illustrator--vector-4989 Best!
Carlos V.

Comment: Object:Rasterise does it all fine nowadays.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming all artwork is vector and not placed raster images...

- Select the image with the mask
- Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` if Expand Appearance is available
- Choose `Object > Expand`
- Click the **Crop** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**

This should trim the artwork to the boundaries of the clipping mask shape. It will leave unfilled objects in some cases, so to clean up I also generally...

- Draw and unfilled, unstroked rectangle
- Choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`
- Hit the delete key.

Or you can deselect everything and use `Object > Path > Clean Up`. Just be aware of the clean up settings. If you have other objects with masks, the Clean Up command may cause issues.

### Additional based on sample image....

(Image was added after I typed the above, so I left it.)

You've got a raster image there. There's **no way** for Illustrator to crop a raster image. None. However, you can use the **[Rasterino](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/rasterino/)** plug in from [www.astutegraphics.com](http://www.astutegraphics.com/) to crop raster images within Illustrator.

(the astute web site seems to be very, very slow at the moment)

Comment: Thanks again, Scott! LOL, maybe I should just email you my questions.

Comment: even google bring me here...

Comment: Quite often I find `Expand` > `Crop` wipes everything except the top object, but `Expand` > `Trim` often works instead.

Comment: @Scott Why is my Expand Appearance grayed out (non active)?

Comment: Expand Appearance is only available if you have some appearance attributes which *can* be expanded. It's not always available and it's nothing to be concerned about if it isn't.

Comment: For me, Expand > Crop worked just fine and I suspect that just Crop would have worked, since the Clipping Mask is there.

Comment: Pathfinder > Crop removed most of the art for me. Pathfinder > Trim worked just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, it is doable with a raster image!

via: http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-how-to-crop-raster-image-in-adobe-illustrator--vector-4989

Involves setting a blend mode other than "normal" and then using flatten transparency.

Select the clipping mask group, then set any Blending Mode for that group. 
[image: set blending mode for clipping mask group]

With the same group still selected, select Object > Flatten Transparency with preserve alpha transparency selected:
[image: flatten transparency]

That's pretty much it. It creates multiple nested clipping groups, but the raster image within is now trimmed to the clipping path.

Comment: Oh sure... _NOW_ I see this after Illustrator 2017 finally adds the ability to crop images to the program!

Answer (score 0):

I did not get multiple nested clipping groups after trying this, and if I did, when I deleted anything, the entire image deleted as well.