# Illustrator - How to export artboard in .ai format with only what's inside artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, artboard, content

I have a huge map made in Illustrator. I made 30 artboards in this map and would like to make an .ai file from each artboard in order to work with smaller files. But each time I save using .ai and chose "use artboard", every artboard is saved with every element of the original file and weights the same size.

How can I save artboard to .ai format with it's content only ?

Here's a screen cap to illustrate : black stroke box is the artboard I want to export in illustrator format without the elements outside it. I don't mean "hide' this elements but really remove them
[image]

Comment: You need to manually crop the elements.

Comment: Check this older case: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20947/trim-a-clipping-mask-in-illustrator Make a clipping mask and try to trim your image along it.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Either clean up the file manually or find another way to work with this large map.